# Recursive function not looping through all the children

Tags: c#, recursion

Here is my Recursive Function to get newly added city to the heirarchical collection.

```
private City getNewlyAddedCity(ObservableCollection<City> cities)
{

    foreach (var city in cities)
    {
        if (city.IsLastAdded)
        {
            return city;
        }
        getNewlyAddedCity(city.Children);
    }

    return null;

}
```

I call this function like :

```
City newlyAddedCity = getNewlyAddedCity(ServiceLocator.Instance.Cities);
```

Every time `newlyAddedCity` is null.

If I put a breakpoint and check, then there is a city which has `IsLastAdded = true`.

I have also checked using Breakpoint that this function does not loop through all the cities in the collection.

Comment: Set 2 breakpoints - one at the "return city;" line, another - at the "return null;" line - and you'll find out why you get null. You lost value that returned by the "getNewlyAddedCity(city.Children);" call.

Comment: @TSV I have kept those breakpoints and checked it. But my recursive function loops through only the ParentCities.

Comment: If there always a city which has `IsLastAdded == true`, then obviously your code will not go to the recursive call `getNewlyAddedCity(city.Children)`.

Comment: Someth like that:
private City getNewlyAddedCity(ObservableCollection<City> cities)
{
    var result = null;
    foreach (var city in cities)
    {
        if (city.IsLastAdded)
        {
            return city;
        }
        result = getNewlyAddedCity(city.Children);
        if(result) { break; }
    }

    return result;

}

Comment: I suppose the "LastAddedCity" is the only in the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private City getNewlyAddedCity(ObservableCollection<City> cities) {
    City result = null;
    foreach(var city in cities) {
        if(city.IsLastAdded) { return city; }
        result = getNewlyAddedCity(city.Children);
        if(result != null) { break; }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This code works fine after making minor changes. I will edit those changes in your answer.

Comment: @Vishal ok :) no problem

Answer (score 2):

You are discarding the return value of `getNewlyAddedCity(city.Children);`. As a result, after the loop the function will return `null`.

You can do this:

```
return getNewlyAddedCity(city.Children);
```

Also, it appears that you want to get the "last added city". Since you already use [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx), why don't you consider using [`CollectionChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I have tried return keyword as you suggested. Then function does not loop through and just checks IsLastAdded in the first city and depending on that it returns to the caller.

Comment: Then `IsLastAdded` on the first city is `true`. Check your logic where you set `IsLastAdded` on the `City` objects.

Comment: IsLastAdded on first city is false

Comment: Ok. `IsLastAdded` attribute of _some_ object in the parent collection must be `true`. Otherwise it will step into the recursive function. You might not be expecting it, but the `City` object with `IsLastAdded` true might be located in the middle of the collection. Please check if it is so.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you

```
return getNewlyAddedCity(city.Children);
```

insted of just calling it?

Comment: I have tried return keyword as you suggested. Then function does not loop through and just checks IsLastAdded in the first city and depending on that it returns to the caller.

Comment: Yeah, as Krumia said, it might be that first one has IsLastAdded set. Also note, that if city.Children == null your code will crash because you are looping that regardless.